# Problems writing up WebBrowser COM events

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I'm developing a project that needs to show HTML that is returned by a third party service. I am currently using a WPF `WebBrowser` to show this output. However this creates a potential security problem in the eyes of my customers. When focus is set to this control you can open any webpage by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> or open Internet Explorer by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. My application is targeted for a kiosk-like environment (Terminal Services).

In the past I've used the WinForms WebBrowser control and was able to sink into the events through COM, however those tactics don't seem to work with the WPF version. My development partners are adamant that we develop a pure WPF application instead of mixing in the WinForms option.

Has anyone had success getting to the `IWebBrowserEvets2`COM interface of the WPF `WebBrowser`? I have been able cast the `WebBrowser.Document` to an `IWebBrowser`, but haven't got to where I need.

Please help me tap into the events so that I can stop the user from creating new windows and other events that might cause "security" problems for my clients. Or is there a better control out there to do the rendering of HTML and basic navigation?

Thanks in advance,
Jerod

Comment: It is not impossible, it is just a lot uglier in WPF.  Type "wpf newwindow2" in a google query, take the first hit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Windows hooks here. Find browser window and install proper keyboard hooks for it. This externals should be helpful for you:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, IntPtr windowTitle);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(Int32 idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hInstance, Int32 threadId);
```

And here is a sample how to use those, but you have to implement KeyboardHookProcedure according to your needs.

```
private IntPtr FindExplorerWindow()
{
    IntPtr wnd = Browser.Handle;
    if (wnd != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        wnd = FindWindowEx(wnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Shell DocObject View", IntPtr.Zero);
        if (wnd != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            wnd = FindWindowEx(wnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Internet Explorer_Server", IntPtr.Zero);
            return wnd;
        }
    }
    return IntPtr.Zero;
}

private void InstallHook()
{
    if (_hHook.ToInt32() > 0) return;

    IntPtr wnd = FindExplorerWindow();
    if (wnd != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        if (_hookProc == null)
        {
            _hookProc = new HookProc(KeyboardHookProcedure);
        }
        _hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, _hookProc, (IntPtr)0, GetCurrentThreadId());
    }
}
```

Good luck!